# _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index') on profile.dart

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

am tying to calling user to appear in profile page the app block when i fixed it i faced other problem which is this one if there any solution can help me

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class UserModel {
  String? uid;
  String? Username;
  String? email;
  String? photoUrl;
  

  UserModel(
      {this.uid, this.email, this.Username,  this.photoUrl});

  // receving data from the server
  factory UserModel.fromMap(Map) {
    return UserModel(
      uid: Map['userId'],
      Username: Map['Username'],
      email: Map['email'],
      photoUrl: Map['photoUrl'],
    );
  }

  // /// sending data to firestore
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'userId': uid,
      'Username': Username,
      'email': email,
      'photoUrl': photoUrl,
    };
  }
}
```

**the error picture**
[image]

Comment: avoid using uppercases for variables and parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Map` as variable name, it is a DataType

```dart
  factory UserModel.fromMap(map) {
    return UserModel(
      uid: map['userId'],
      Username: map['Username'],
      email: map['email'],
      photoUrl: map['photoUrl'],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

by using this :

```
     // receving data from the server
  factory UserModel.fromMap(Map) {
    return UserModel(
      uid: Map['userId'],
      Username: Map['Username'],
      email: Map['email'],
      photoUrl: Map['photoUrl'],
    );
  }
```

you're referring to the `Map` as it type, so it throws the error.
you need to referr to a `Map` object, not the `Map` type, so try this :

```
    // receving data from the server
  factory UserModel.fromMap(Map data) {
    return UserModel(
      uid: data['userId'],
      Username: data['Username'],
      email: data['email'],
      photoUrl: data['photoUrl'],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

while feting the data you need to declare the response as Map<String, dynamic>? even after doing that also if the error remains, try adding Map['userId].toString() || Map['userId] as String. refer below code

```
      final favoriteResponse = await http.get(url);
  final favoriteData =
      json.decode(favoriteResponse.body) as Map<String, dynamic>?;
  final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];
  extractedData?.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
    loadedProducts.add(Product(
        id: prodId,
        title: prodData['title'],
        description: prodData['description'],
        price: prodData['price'],
        imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl'],
        isFavorite:
            favoriteData == null ? false : favoriteData[prodId] ?? false));
  });
  _items = loadedProducts;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure

> userId

is a String in your firestore